# pipenv Locking Failed when installing QuantLib-Python

Tags: quantlib, pipenv-install

I tried to create an environment in the folder quantengine (on my MacOS V.11.3 - Big Sur) by first installing the QuantLib-Python package.  It seems to install, but I get the Locking Failed error.  Any idea what might be causing this? I installed first pyenv via brew.  I set Python 3.9.4 as global.  I then installed pipenv via pip.

[screenshot zsh shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgHlN.jpg)

Comment: Try using `pip install quantlib` first.  If that fails, there might be no version of QuantLib on PyPI that works on your Mac.  Is it a M1 machine or an older one?

Comment: Hello Mr. Ballabio.  Thanks for your reply.  I 'pip install QuantLib' globally and then in a local subfolder 'pipenv install QuantLib-Python' (as I want to work within an environment using pyenv+pipenv), but unfortunately got the same result.   I have an "old" Mac (from 2015).
QuantLib-Python does seem to be installed and working in my subfolder, but on installing the package pipenv outputs this "Locking Failed!" message.

Comment: If the global `pip install QuantLib` worked, it should mean that a compatible wheel for your machine is available.  Have you tried `pipenv install QuantLib`? (The QuantLib-Python module was obsoleted a while ago).  If that doesn't work, I'm not familiar wih pipenv, but have you tried the suggestions that pipenv wrote to console in your screenshot?

Comment: Hello Mr. Ballabio.  I tried with `pipenv install QuantLib` and obtained the same result.   I tried the first suggestion on the console: "First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again", but that didn't help either.   I will try the second option (bypassing the Locking mechanism) and see if then using the `pipenv graph` helps.
By the way, from your comment above, I should not use `pip(env) install QuantLib-Python`?  Should I stick to only QuantLib?
Kind regards.

Comment: `QuantLib-Python` was the old name.  It should cause `QuantLib` (the new name) to be installed as a dependency, but you can install `QuantLib` directly instead.